# 3D view is completely warped!

Tags: rendering, camera

I've been using blender for a while now, and this has never happened to me before. I was designing an ad in Blender 2.73a for a game that I made. However, when I went into camera view, everything looked bigger then in the final render. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

P.S. I've been using blender for about a year, but I still don't know all the buttons, so please no jargon!

[image]

[image: 3D view and final render]

Comment: pressing home-key in camera view works too.

Comment: thx. I can't believe I didn't figure that one out. Help very much appreciated.

Comment: bang, brain explodes.

Answer (score 4):

This actually isn't to hard to fix.

You are zoomed in (very far) when looking in the camera view. if you zoom out, <kbd>Middle Mouse ↕</kbd>  you will see the proper bounds for the active camera.

[image]